# Does trailing wildcard use index? (where column like 'value%')

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-19c

I have a query on a Varchar2 field in an Oracle table:

```
select column from tbl where column like 'value%'
```

That query uses a trailing wildcard.

---

Question:

Is Oracle capable of using an index on that column, when a trailing wildcard is used?

Comment: Look up sargeabilty! You **do** know that you ca  test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can. This is just a range predicate really:

```
Where column >= 'value'
And column < 'valuf'
```

A wildcard somewhere else in the string will change how much of the string can be used as the `access` predicate on the index. This is then just a cost based decision by the optimizer - how much of the index will it have to read and how many rows of the table will it need to lookup up from that.